# How to display 1 table data to 2 columns each data 1-n in fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf, calculated-columns

I have a tabledata that exported into pdf. Im using [Fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)  and Codeigniter.
First my fpdf works good, and i can export it.

I need to make this table into 2 column, its hard to find the doc about it
but i can make it to like this one

[image: I have table data]

**This is my code**

```
      foreach ($lists as $key => $value) 
  {
    $c++;
    /*% total data per page, kenapa %total == 1 karena akan di addPage Bukan Ketika saat mencapai total, tapi total + 1*/
    if ($c%99999 == 1 || $c == 1) 
    {
      $pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4');
      $pdf->SetDrawColor(209, 212, 207);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

      
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
      $pdf->Cell(280,6,'Data Stok Barang Toko',0,1,'C');
      $pdf->Ln();
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
      $pdf->Cell(280,6,'Mulya Indah',0,1,'C');
     
      
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
      
      $pdf->Cell(40, 6, 'Tanggal Cetak', 0, 'L', FALSE);
      $pdf->Cell(130, 6, ': '.date('d M Y'), 0, 'L', FALSE);

     
      $pdf->Ln();
      $pdf->Cell(40,6, 'Halaman', 0, 'L', FALSE);
      $pdf->Cell(130,6, ': '.ceil($c/76).' / '.number_format(ceil(sizeof($lists)/76)), 0, 'L', FALSE);
     
      $pdf->Ln();

      $pdf->Ln();

      $pdf->Ln();
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
   
        $pdf->Cell(5,15,'',0);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'ID',1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(100,6,'Nama Barang',1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'Stok',1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(5,15,'',0); 
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'ID',1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(100,6,'Nama Barang',1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,'Stok',1,1);
     
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    
     
    }
    $is_spit = $c %2== 0 ? 1 : 0;

 
    $is_lastrow = $c %2== 0 ? 60 : 50;

    $pdf->Cell(5,15,'',0); 
    $pdf->Cell(15,6,number_format($c),1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(100,6,$value['nama_barang'],1,0);
    $data =$value['stock_sisa'];
   
    $pdf->CustomTxt($data,$is_spit);//just for background $this->Cell(10,6,"$num",1,$row,0,1);
    
  }
  $pdf->Output('I','DataStok_'.date('Ymd').'.pdf');
  
  /*gaperlu return, $pdf->Output == merubah header content ketoke, dadi return dibawah gabakal kebaca*/
}
```

But I want like this one

```
|no|name|   |no|name | 
|-----------|--------|
| 1| txt|   | 6 | txt|
| 2| txt|   | 7 | txt|
| 3| txt|   | 8 | txt|
| 4| txt|   | 9 | txt|
| 5| txt|   | 10| txt|
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy them into your post and format them appropriately.

Comment: ok let me change it then